# ¿Cómo cancelar una petición asíncrona con d3.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, d3-v4.js

Tengo una app móvil que realiza una llamada AJAX para mandar datos al servidor y obtener una respuesta en JSON que se utilizará para actualizar una tabla con valores:

```
d3.json(
        "http://mipagina.com/?param1=1&param2=2",
        function(d) {
          if (d.valid) {
            // actualizar tabla
          }
        }
     );
```

Si por cualquier motivo quiero cancelar esa petición, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirando los fuentes, tienes el metodo [`abort`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/src/request.js#L121) quien a su vez invoca el metodo [`abort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) de XMLHttpRequest (d3.json se basa en request).

```
var req = d3.json(
    "http://mipagina.com/?param1=1&param2=2",
    function(d) {
      if (d.valid) {
        // actualizar tabla
      }
    }
);

// cancelo
req.abort();
```